# pure abstract class have function with stl is dll-interface?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm beginer writting dll library. I've read about ABI compatibility. But I'm not sure It is right that pure abstract class could have stl return type or stl params.

in dll

foo.h

```
class IFoo {
  void Hello(const std::string&); // this declaration could be possible?
}

void export Inject(IFoo& foo);
```

foo.cc

```
IFoo* g_foo;

void Inject(IFoo& foo) {
  g_foo = &foo;
}
```

`*g_foo` It could be problem?

in application

```
class Foo : public IFoo {
 // implemented
}

Foo foo;
Inject(foo);
```

Comment: It can have STL return type and params.

Comment: @kiner_shah application could pass derived class to dll-side and dll-side could use it?

Comment: Write the code, run it and see for yourself.

Comment: Passing standard library (not STL, that's [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)) objects, or references or pointers to such objects, is depending on the [**ABI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). If the DLL and the application is built with the same ABI then it should work fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? See you using visual studio or gcc or do you want to be compatible with both? If visual studio are you using a single version or a mix of versions?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have to support msvc and gcc. in windows, I build library with clang-cl and apllication uses cl import dll library

Comment: Then no, you can't use standard library types in your interfaces